# How to handle null user inputs within adaptive cards only

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

How can I show a user a red color message inside the adaptive card itself, when the user tries to hit the ok button without providing any input in the drop-down present in my adaptive cards. I don't want my Luis agent to handle it I want my UI to handle the above scenario

Answer (score -1):

Adaptive Cards don't currently support client-side validation as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336440/5209435) from a MSFT employee. You will have to handle this scenario in your code that processes the user input. If the input is not valid, then you could send a message to the user saying please fill in the required fields X, Y, and Z, followed by the original Adaptive Card.

**Edit - Additional sources**

See this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1978#issuecomment-505087998) from a month ago about validation coming in Version 1.3, along with [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3081) which is tracking the current status of the input validation functionality.

Comment: I have seen this.. but that response is of 2017..till now their are no changes  being made?